# how do i fix this error about pallet rack network?

Tags: anylogic

I am creating network with different pallet rack and paths and the model gives me this error :"Pallet rack root.palletRack_360: couldn't find the path for the cell #0".Why?
thanks for the help.
here the model:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhfvS-jv8ukShIRtDNG-DUolG-Z6Ow?e=SBUOph
[image: animation error]

[image: console error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, you have accidentally created more than 1 network. However, agents can only navigate within 1 network. See how many networks you have by checking the "Projects" view under Main->Presentation->level

Below, I accidentally created 2 networks:

[image]

Combine items from different networks by ensuring that every path is connected properly

Comment: i had the same error but i have one network. Other reasons?

Comment: You could still have several networks in several agent types, depends on your model structure. Is everything on Main?

Comment: yes (if you want,check with the onedrive link)

Comment: make sure the pallet is properly part of the network. It needs a path through it such that it is flagged "green", see the Help to learn more

Answer (score 0):

If there's a Path point inside the aisle (which turns green when in network) of the rack, then you may get this error. Try keeping just the continuous path without any points in the aisle.